# jQuerys $.trim(), bug or poorly written?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

[`$.trim()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) uses the following RegExp to trim a string:

```
/^(\s|\u00A0)+|(\s|\u00A0)+$/g
```

As it turns out, this can be pretty ugly, Example:

```
var mystr = '    some test --          more text            new test                                         xxx';
mystr = mystr.replace(/^(\s|\u00A0)+|(\s|\u00A0)+$/g, "");
```

This code **hangs** Firefox and Chrome, it just takes like forever. "`mystr`" contains whitespaces but mostly `hex 160(A0)` characters. This "problem" does only occur, if there is no prepending `whitespace/A0`, but somewhere within the string. I have no clue why this happens.

This expression:

```
/^[\n\r\t \xA0]+|[\n\r\t \xA0]$/g
```

just works fine in all tested scenarios. Maybe a better pattern for that?

Source: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.js

**UPDATE**

It looks like you can't copy&paste this example string, at some points those `A0` characters are replaced. `Firebug console` will also replace the characters on pasting, you have to create your own string in a sepperate html file/editor to test this.

Comment: It seems like SO converted your A0s to 20s (at least when I cut and paste your code into Emacs).

Comment: `$.trim()` doesn't use that regex, in fact in most cases it uses no regex...what version of jQuery are you looking at?

Comment: @Nick: that regex is used as of 1.4.2

Comment: @All: See Peter Jaric's comment and my update

Comment: @jAndy - Look at jQuery core: http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L575 using `trim`, defined here: http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L58

Comment: @Nick: thanks for the links. Again, in v1.4.2 the native `trim` is not used.

Comment: @Nick: please check your charCodeAt(0), its 32

Comment: There's a similar bug listed from a month ago in the [jQuery bugtracker](http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/6605). Catastrophic backtracking, which I regularly do, but seldom in code.

Comment: @jAndy, maybe you should add a link to the source to your question, to avoid misunderstandings: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.js

Comment: @Andrew: I'm actually eased by that, means I did not lose my mind

Comment: Out of idle curiosity, @jAndy, did you stumble across this for real, or did you just see that bad regex and write a test?

Comment: @Pointy: I'm receiving xml files for a project, containing snippets from news agencys. I could not figure out why some snippets hung my browsers.

Comment: Wow that's amazing. I'm no automata theorist but something in my brain said "ick" when I saw that regex in your question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a [known bug](http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/6605), as said in comments, and Crescent is right that it's this way in **1.4.2**, but it's already fixed for the next release.

You can test the speed of `String.prototype.trim` on your string here: http://jsfiddle.net/dLLVN/
I get around 79ms in Chrome 117ms in Firefox for a million runs...so this will fix the hanging issue :)

As for the fix, [take a look at the current source that'll be in 1.4.3](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L575), the native trimming is now used.

There were 2 commits in march for this:

- http://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/141ad3c3e21e7734e67e37b5fb39782fe11b3c18
- http://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/ba8938d444b9a49bdfb27213826ba108145c2e50

---

[1.4.2 `$.trim()` function](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.2/src/core.js#L570):

```
trim: function( text ) {
    return (text || "").replace( rtrim, "" );
},
```

---

[1.4.3 `$.trim()` function](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L575):

```
//earlier: 
trim = String.prototype.trim

//new trim here
trim: trim ?
  function( text ) {
    return text == null ?
      "" : 
      trim.call( text ); 
  } :

  // Otherwise use our own trimming functionality
  function( text ) { 
    return text == null ? 
      "" :
      text.toString().replace( trimLeft, "" ).replace( trimRight, "" );
  }
```

The `trimLeft` and `trimRight` vary, depending on whether you're in IE or not, like this:

```
trimLeft = /^\s+/,
trimRight = /\s+$/,

// Verify that \s matches non-breaking spaces
// (IE fails on this test)
if ( !/\s/.test( "\xA0" ) ) {
  trimLeft = /^[\s\xA0]+/;
  trimRight = /[\s\xA0]+$/;
}
```

Comment: it would be nice to see the `trimLeft` and `trimRight` expressions as well.

Comment: @jAndy - He posted them as a link. Click the first commit link.

Comment: @jAndy - Added the relevant bits and links to the branch tags so you can see the changes in git :)

Answer (score 7):

Normally an expression like `^\s+|\s+$` should be enough for trimming, since `\s` is supposed to match all space characters, even `\0xa0` non-breaking spaces<sup>1</sup>. This expression should run without causing any problems.

Now probably some browser that jQuery wants to support doesn't match `\0xa0` with `\s` and to work around this problem jQuery added the alternative `(\s|\0xa0)`, to trim away non-breaking spaces on that browser too.

With this change, the second part of the regex looks like `(\s|\0xa0)+$`, which leads to problems in browsers where `\0xa0` is also matched by `\s`. In a string containing a long sequence of `\0xa0` characters, each character can be matched by `\s` or `\0xa0`, leading to lots of alternative matches and exponentially many combinations how different matches can be combined. If this sequence of `\0xa0` characters is not at the end of the string, the trailing `$` condition can never be fulfilled, no matter which spaces are matched by `\s` and which are matched by `\0xax`, but the browser doesn't know this and tries all combinations, potentially searching for a very long time.

The simplified expression you suggest will not be sufficient since `\s` is supposed to match all unicode space characters, not just the well-known ASCII ones.

---

<sup>1</sup> According to [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#ref_equivalent_s), `\s` is equivalent to `[\t\n\v\f\r \u00a0\u2000\u2001\u2002\u2003\u2004\u2005\u2006\u2007\u2008\u2009\u200a\u200b\u2028\u2029\u3000]`

Answer (score 5):

As it turned out, this behavior was posted on jQuerys bugtracker one month ago:

http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/6605

Thanks to `Andrew` for pointing me to that.

Comment: That bug report is funny because Trac seems to eat uparrow characters. Thus both the broken "rtrim" and the suggested fix look incorrect.

Comment: jAndy - +1 I see that I had been looking at the most recent commit. (Thanks to @Pointy for giving me heads up.) But still, I can't get either the regex or `$.trim()` (which are the same) to fail in Firefox. I wonder why that is.